# $_POST $_GET запросы не читаются

Tags: yii, post, javascript, xmlhttprequest

В общем, для работы $_POST и $_GET подключил XMLHttpRequest:

```
function sendRequest(type,path, data,callback){
    var xmlhttp = getXmlHttp(); // Создаём объект XMLHTTP
    xmlhttp.open(type, path, true); // Открываем асинхронное соединение
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() { // Ждём ответа от сервера
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) { // Ответ пришёл
        if(xmlhttp.status == 200) { // Сервер вернул код 200 (что хорошо)
          callback(xmlhttp.responseText); // возвращаем ответ сервера
        }
      }
    };    
    xmlhttp.send(data); // Отправляем запрос
 }
```

в rules в main.php пишу:

```
'send' => 'USER/default/send',
```

в экшне:

```
public function actionSend()
    {
        echo $_POST['name']; // если "OK" писать от правляется, а $_POST не читается
    }
```

отправляю так:

```
var query = 'name='+o.name.value+'&phone='+o.phone.value+'&massage='+o.massage.value;
            sendRequest('POST','/send',query,function(data){
                alert(data);
            });
```

в firebug'е:

[image]

Что для Yii не хватает еще, не знаю , в обычном php все отправляется и читается, может, кто-нибудь знает, работал с XMLHttpRequest в yii?

P.S.: Аналогично $_GET тоже не читает, сработал только тогда, когда в rules написал:

```
'/search/<q:.*?>' => 'TRACKING/default/search',
```

и тогда с браузера пишу так

```
sitename.ru/search/query_data //так работает
```

а в начале делал так в рулес писал так:

```
'/search' => 'TRACKING/default/search',
```

и запрос делал так c адресной строки:

```
sitename.ru/search?q=query_data, не работает:(
```

В общем, люди добрые, SOS!

## добавил заголовки:

[image]

Comment: > var query = 'name='+o.name.value+'&phone='+o.phone.value+'&massage='+o.massage.value;

угадайте, что произойдет, когда в *massage* придет амперсанд (&)

> 'send' => 'USER/default/send',

Что разворачивается в "модуль: USER, контроллер: default, экшен: send". У вас это точно в модуле?

> echo $_POST['name'];

    Yii::app()->request->getPost('name');

Вообще больше похоже на проблемы с роутингом.

Comment: @Etki, да, это в модуле USER, а

    Yii::app()->request->getPost('name')

тоже не работает. 
Цитирую "Вообще больше похоже на проблемы с роутингом." - да, я тоже так думаю, только вот как это решить?

Comment: Заголовки, которые отправляете на сервер, покажите)
Интересует заголовок: Content-Type

Comment: @nolka, добавил.

Answer (score 1):

ха-ха-ха-ха)))
оказывается при отправки POST Content-Type надо менять на

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
```

Comment: Может, и при $_GET тоже так делать надо, я еще не протестировал.